# How to configure k3s agent node not to bind on 0.0.0.0

Tags: kubernetes, rancher, k3s

I want to setup a small k3s cluster:

- 1 master, 1 agent
- both server have a public ip and a local ip (10.x.x.x)
- I want both nodes to listen only on the local ip so no port is reachable via internet (I will let the load balancer dispatch traffic to the local network or setup NAT rules to dispatch 443 traffic to the LAN address)

This works as expected for the master node when I execute the following command:

```
curl -sfL https://get.k3s.io | INSTALL_K3S_EXEC="server --disable=servicelb --node-name=master --bind-address=10.0.0.3 --advertise-address=10.0.0.3" K3S_TOKEN=xxx sh -s -
```

running ifconfig on the master node shows me everything is listening to the 10.0.0.3 address only. On the agent node it looks different. I start the agent with:

```
curl -sfL https://get.k3s.io | INSTALL_K3S_EXEC="agent --node-ip=10.0.0.2 --node-external-ip=10.0.0.2" K3S_URL=https://10.0.0.3:6443 K3S_TOKEN=yyy::server:xxx sh -s -
```

the communication between agent and node seems to happen over the private network now. However, when I run netstat i see that the agent port 10250 is bound to 0.0.0.0:

```
tcp6       0      0 :::10250                :::*                    LISTEN      0          83060      6812/k3s agent
```

passing the bind-address variable leads to a crash of the agent node as it tells me that the bind-address parameter is not supported in agent mode.

Any idea how I can configure the agent not to listen to the public interface?